# How to sort JsonNode array List

Tags: java, arraylist, jackson

I am trying to sort below array node within my json payload. Should be sort by `name` element

Before:

```
"empData": [
    {
      "name": "Jhon",
      "age": 33
    },
    {
      "name": "Sam",
      "age": 24
    },
    {
      "name": "Mike",
      "age": 65
    },
    {
      "name": "Jenny",
      "age": 33
    }
  ]
```

Expected:

```
"empData": [
    {
      "name": "Jenny",
      "age": 33
    },
    {
      "name": "Jhon",
      "age": 33
    },
    {
      "name": "Mike",
      "age": 65
    },
    {
      "name": "Sam",
      "age": 24
    }
  ]
```

I was trying below option:

```
private static final ObjectMapper SORTED_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

static {
    SORTED_MAPPER.configure(SerializationFeature.ORDER_MAP_ENTRIES_BY_KEYS, true);
}

public static JsonNode sortJsonArrayList(final JsonNode node) throws IOException {
    final Object obj = SORTED_MAPPER.treeToValue(node, Object.class);
    final String json = SORTED_MAPPER.writeValueAsString(obj);
    return objectMapper.readTree(json);
}
```

But not sure how to select name key for sorting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public JsonNode some(JsonNode node){
        //find list of objects that contains field name
        List<JsonNode> dataNodes = node.findParents("name");
        //sort it
        List<JsonNode> sortedDataNodes = empDataNodes
                .stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(o -> o.get("name").asText()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        //return the same Json structure as in method parameter
        ArrayNode arrayNode = objectMapper.createObjectNode().arrayNode().addAll(sortedEmpDataNodes);
        return objectMapper.createObjectNode().set("empData", arrayNode);
}
```

You can debug it step by step and see how it works.

Comment: Can we have same approach to sort with two keys?

Comment: You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805606/how-to-sort-by-two-fields-in-java) answer and add some of it solution in `.sorted()` method

Comment: Thanks. found https://stackoverflow.com/a/8036545/2303693 also which does the work perfectly

Answer (score 2):

`ORDER_MAP_ENTRIES_BY_KEYS` is the feature which enables Map sorting by Map keys. As your result type is not a Map this sorting will not be applied. To sort array you can create custom deserialiser or sort deserialised array in place. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42383816/4154048) answer describes how this can be achieved.